# PHP Regex for similarity check

Tags: php, regex

Can you think of any regular expression that resolves these similarities in PHP? The idea is to get a match without considering the last letters.

```
<?php


$word1 = 'happyness';
$word2 = 'happys';

if (substr($word1, 0, -4) == substr($word2, 0, -1))
{
    echo 'same word1';
}


$word1 = 'kisses';
$word2 = 'kiss';


if (substr($word1, 0, -2) == $word2)
{
    echo 'same word2';
}


$word1 = 'consonant';
$word2 = 'consonan';


if (substr($word1, 0, -1) == $word2)
{
    echo 'same word3';
}
```

Comment: How did first one match?

Comment: Last tree letters. Therefore, happyness would not match.

Comment: @Raymont Output does create a match for you https://3v4l.org/S2SfL

Comment: Can you explain the rules behind this matching? Please do so by editing your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting the words together like `happys happyness` and [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) as many [word characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) from word 1 as word 2 matches. [See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oUbzQo/3). Use it with the `i` [flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for casless matching.

```
^(\w+)\w* \1
```

To use this in PHP with [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) see [this PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##bZBLT4QwFIXX9ldcG5JSJZBhO44GV67MJC4BCXbKI8y02JYhxvjbseWxMa56e75z7z1t3/TT9PB0fDki5I1SnTQcIEWkKfv@SxM4PMJSC641CRDpWq35ClztNCaFlqIUZpG3q0PJB6t1tejJMzvxiqB8j1AlFS9Z4687kzfwOmfyrhQBjIU2pTJFKwxXmjPje13gmOscBDOtFP@Z3LCdNbozpujbjuKskYBTHC4wxMFaxiHOAe@tpa38XvG6uJTGJiLRu5@N9zQb7yDbRS0JZvg5SMO3DSQiNMSAQ/jL4pkFnhwMpehm2S6vXJ3tJ7aiht5GhkrJC8zp3ZttIGtPd3mIMzEn4mfNt@ZXCXOw25n9oGn6BQ)

```
preg_match('/^(\w+)\w* \1/i', preg_quote($word1,'/')." ".preg_quote($word2,'/'), $out);
```

where `$out[1]` holds the captures or `$out` would be an empty array if there wasn't a match.

Comment: Well done, it's a good robust solution to false positives, which is a big concern too.

Comment: Thanks @Raymont, glad it is of help!

Comment: @Raymont Can you give some examples of false positives?

Comment: This is a false positive, only with the first letter it achieves a match (that's why I put a condition for at least 5 letters).

$word1 = 'halloween';

$word2 = 'h';

echo 'match ' .preg_match('/^(\w+)\w* \1/i', preg_quote($word1,'/')." ".preg_quote($word2,'/'), $out);

Answer (score 2):

You could use a small helper function, the first function just matches up to the length of the second string, so doesn't care how many characters it truncates.  The main code works similar to your code except it uses the length of the second value as the length of the substring to take...

```
function match( string $a, string $b )  {
    return substr($a, 0, strlen($b)) === $b;
}
```

This function is slightly more complicated as it takes into account a maximum gap length...

```
function match( string $a, string $b, int $length = 3 )  {
    $len = max(strlen($a)-$length, strlen($b));
    return substr($a, 0, $len) === $b;
}
```

So call it something along the lines of

```
$word1 = 'happyness';
$word2 = 'happys';

if (match($word1,$word2))
{
    echo 'same word1';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match these data with regex as `/^word2/` against `word1`. So regex would check if `word1` starts with `word2` or not, because of `^` symbol at the start.

It's always better to [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) before matching to escape regex meta characters for accurate results.

```
<?php


$tests = [
        [
          'happyness',
          'happys'
        ],
        [
            'kisses',
            'kiss'
        ],
        [
            'consonant',
            'consonan'
        ]
    ];

$filtered = array_filter($tests,function($values){
    $values[1] = preg_quote($values[1]);
    return preg_match("/^$values[1]/",$values[0]) === 1;
});

print_r($filtered);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/SLf15

Answer (score 2):

You could also do a small function to find the similarity between the given 2 words. It could look like:

```
function similarity($word1, $word2)
{
    $splittedWord1 = str_split($word1);
    $splittedWord2 = str_split($word2);

    $similarChars = array_intersect_assoc($splittedWord1, $splittedWord2);

    return count($similarChars) / max(count($splittedWord1), count($splittedWord2));
}

var_dump(similarity('happyness', 'happys'));
var_dump(similarity('happyness', 'testhappys'));
var_dump(similarity('kisses', 'kiss'));
var_dump(similarity('consonant', 'consonan'));
```

The result would look like:

```
float(0.55555555555556)
int(0)
float(0.66666666666667)
float(0.88888888888889)
```

Based on the resulted percentage you could decide if the given words should be considered the same or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure regex is the answer here.

You could try [similar_text()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php), which returns the number of similar characters (and optionally sets a percentage value to a variable). Maybe if you consider the last two letters as non-important, you can see if the `strlen() - $skippedCharacters` is the same as what is matched. For example:

```php
$skippedCharacters = 2;

$word1 = 'kisses';
$word2 = 'kiss';

$match = similar_text($word1, $word2);

if ($match + $skippedCharacters >= strlen($word1))
{
    echo 'same word2';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the PHP levenshtein function.

*The levenshtein() function returns the Levenshtein distance between two strings. The Levenshtein distance is the number of characters you have to replace, insert or delete to transform string1 into string2.*

```
$lev = levenshtein($word1, $word2);
```

The lower the number the bigger the similarity.